# SQLCMD from SSMS is not working; connecting to Azure SQL Database

Tags: azure-sql-database, ssms, sqlcmd

Running this from my SQL Server Management Studuio (SSMS) connecting to Azure sql database. I am using SQLCMD mode of SSMS.

```
:Connect -S taiobdemo1.database.windows.net -d taiobcustomer -U sqlusername -P strongpw
```

Getting this error:

> A fatal scripting error occurred. Incorrect syntax was encountered
>   while parsing :Connect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `:connnect` [SqlCmd](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sqlcmd-utility?view=sql-server-2017) command does not allow you to specify a target database.  You'll always connect to your default database.  So it's pretty useless in Azure SQL Database, as you'll be connected to Master and won't be able to switch.

eg

```
:Connect xxxx.database.windows.net  -U someuser -P xxxx
select db_name()
```

Will always output `master`